# Lagrange Multiplier problem with three variables

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I struggle a bit with this problem:

Use Lagrange's methode to find the maximum value to $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z $ when $D={(x,y,z)\in R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=36}$

So I have done this:

1. $y^2z=\lambda2x$
2. $2xyz=\lambda2y \rightarrow 0=2y(\lambda-xz)$
3. $xy^2=\lambda 2z$
4. $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$

But I'dont know what to do next, because I have not worked with 3 variables when in comes to Lagrange methode before. I thought about $y=0$ or $xz=\lambda$. But I don't know if this works. I have tried, but I always end up with some weird expressions, and never real numbers. Does anyone have some tips?

Comment: The second equation tells you that (besides $y=0$) $\lambda=xz$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have formulated the equations(1, 2, 3) correctly. Solve them to get
$$\
x^2 = \lambda \\
y^2 = 2\lambda \\
z^2 = \lambda
$$
Plug these in the constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$. If you get multiple solutions try each solution and find which gives the maximum value. This is because Lagrangian does not always give the global maximum/minimum.

Comment: How did you manage to express all three variables in terms of lambda?

Comment: Dividing eqn 1 by eqn 3 to get $x^2=z^2$. Plugging it in 2 solves the problem.

Comment: Ohh, but why can we divide the equations by one another? Can this always be done? I'm sorry for all the questions, I'm just currious and really want to understand this fully

Comment: You are correct. Its a bad way to solve like this. Basically, we ignore the cases that terms in numerator and denominator can go to zero. But, in your case it's fine as we know that $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$ cannot be the solution because that just makes the objective function 0.

Comment: I see! Thank you for a great answer!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Indeed you have 2 cases. The first sets $y=0$ which forces the function to have zero value, and since you are looking for a maximum, this is definitely not optimal.

That forces $xz = \lambda$. Can you plug into 1st and 3rd equations and use the results to plug into the 4th?

Comment: I think I got it know! I got that $y=\pm 2\sqrt {2}$. The thing that confusses me the most is how I determine that $y=0$ is not an answer to consider further. I understand your point; that $f(x,y,z)=0$ if that was the case. But could not 0 be a maximum value?

Comment: @Mathomat55 It's easy to see you are picking points from the sphere or radius $6$ and multiplying the coordinates in a certain way, so any point with all positive coordinates will produce a higher value than $0$... if you were looking for a saddle point, that would be a different story

Comment: I understand now, thank you so for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**Only for control:**

The minimum of 
$$x(36-x^2-z^2)z$$

occurs at a stationary point,

$$\begin{cases}(36-3x^2-z^2)z=0,\\x(36-x^2-3z^2)=0.\end{cases}$$

The equations describe two ellipses and two straight lines, forming a total of nine intersections,

$$(x,z)=(0,0),(0,\pm6),(\pm6,0),(\pm3,\pm3).$$

The corresponding values of $f$ are $0$ and $\pm162$. The maximum occurs four times, at $(3,\pm3\sqrt2,3)$ and $(-3,\pm3\sqrt2,-3)$.